# Why is $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=\ln(n^{\frac{1}{n}})$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I've seen this being used in a proof for limits and can't figure out why it is true.

Comment: $\ln (a^{b})=b\ln a$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you, that's it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just uses the logarithm law $\log(x^M) = M \log(x)$.